# Prove that $2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} < 2n + 1$ for all positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I've been testing this with many values and it seems to always be true. I've been trying to rework the inequality into a form where it's much more obvious that the left hand side is always less than the right, but can't seem to do it. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks.

Comment: Generalise to arbitrary numbers: $2ab \leqslant a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: square both sides

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{4n^2+4n}<\sqrt{4n^2+4n+1}=2n+1.
$$
**Note.** This inequality holds for every non-negative real $n$ (not only integer.)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It's worth noting that this proves it for all $n\ge0$ not just integers

Comment: That is in fact right!

Answer (score 3):

By the AM-GM inequality, $\displaystyle\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}\le\frac{2n+1}{2}$.

Comment: This should be a standard tool in any inequality toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

$$2n+1 - 2\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}=(\underbrace{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}}_{\ne 0})^2 >0$$